# ¿Cómo ocultar una columna de una tabla con Bootstrap 5.2 dependiendo del tamaño de pantalla?

Tags: html, bootstrap, html-tabla

Creando una pagina me encontré con el inconveniente de no poder ocultar una determinada columna de una tabla cuando el tamaño de pantalla es sm o inferior. Probé el la siguiente clase en thead:

> `<th class="d-none d-sm-block" scope="col">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>`

Lo apliqué también en cada fila de la columna DESCRIPCIÓN de la tabla. El encabezado DESCRIPCIÓN como también cada fila de dicha columna si se oculta en pantallas sm o inferior, pero el problema está en que se muestra la columna totalmente vacía. Mi código de la tabla es el siguente:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">ARTICULO</th>
                                    <th class="d-none d-sm-block" scope="col">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                                    <th scope="col">PRECIO</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="">
                                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
                                    <td><span class="d-none d-sm-block">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, earum
                                        impedit quis excepturi amet nesciunt sunt voluptatem obcaecati voluptatum
                                        eaque nisi eos vero harum. Odio harum exercitationem facere nesciunt alias.
                                    </span></td>
                                    <td>$58745</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="">
                                    <td>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing</td>
                                    <td><span class="d-none d-sm-block">
                                        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, debitis,
                                        saepe sed laborum dolore ipsam id modi odio itaque enim eaque perferendis
                                        porro corrupti illum ut. Praesentium voluptatibus vero quo.</span></td>
                                    <td>$98574</td>
                                </tr>
                             </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso te ocurre porque no has puesto el d-none en la columna, sino en un span **dentro** de la columna.

```
<span class="d-none d-sm-block">
```

Si lo pones en la definición de columna (**td**) te funcionará bien.

Ejemplo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ARTICULO</th>
        <th class="d-none d-lg-block" scope="col">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
        <th scope="col">PRECIO</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="">
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
        <td class="d-none d-lg-block"><span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, earum
            impedit quis excepturi amet nesciunt sunt voluptatem obcaecati voluptatum
            eaque nisi eos vero harum. Odio harum exercitationem facere nesciunt alias.
          </span></td>
        <td>$58745</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="">
        <td>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing</td>
        <td class="d-none d-lg-block"><span>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, debitis,
            saepe sed laborum dolore ipsam id modi odio itaque enim eaque perferendis
            porro corrupti illum ut. Praesentium voluptatibus vero quo.</span></td>
        <td>$98574</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciona. Solo Hay un pequeño inconveniente que tengo ahora y es que cuando puse class="d-none d-lg-block" a cada td de la columna descripción se redujo el alto de cada registro de la columna Descripción con respectos a los otros registros de la tabla. ¿sabes como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: mmm... no se que puede estar pasando... ¿has quitado lo que contenia el span en esas columnas?

Comment: A mi no me sucede eso que cuentas. En [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/a02otdc6/) puedes jugar a ampliar y reducir la ventana para ver como aparece y desaparece esa columna descripcion.